# ASP.NET web site builds locally, but throws MSB3268 on the build server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, msbuild

I added a project to my web site solution. Everything built fine locally and on the build server.

I added a line in web code to call a method in the new project. Everything built and worked fine locally, but it broke the build on the build server.

I got a pile of errors going something like this:

> warning MSB3268: The primary reference "C:...\ProjectName.dll" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "Assembly.Name (e.g. System.Runtime)", Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "C:...\ProjectName.dll" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".

After all the warnings, the build failed with an error indicating the namespace ProjectName could not be found. Makes sense considering the project's dependencies couldn't be resolved.

At first I wondered if there was an issue with targeting the wrong framework. But there was a mix of 4.0 and 4.5 projects referenced by the 4.5 website. This was the first one that had failed.

The only difference between this and the other projects was that it referenced third-party DLLs. So apparently their dependencies are the ones that couldn't be resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This post held the key: http://devsilos.blogspot.com/2014/10/msb3268-while-targeting-aspnet-web-site.html

The author suggests:

> aspnet_compiler for some reason does not take into account the .dll-s that reside under the Facade directory of 4.5 assemblies (C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades).
>   It looks only under
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5

My extrapolation on that idea is that maybe the compiler doesn't take into account DDLs in the Facades directory *if they're referenced by a third-party DLL rather than directly from your project*.

The solution, as suggested by the author, was to find the DLLs matching assemblies mentioned in the `MSB3268` warnings and copy them from Facades to its parent directory.

I think my problem/solution differed from the blog's in that it had nothing to do with the .NET Framework version targeted. It had only to do with whether the build server's compiler looked in the right places to resolve third-party DLLs' dependencies.

The problem caused about ten hours of frustration. I hope this helps someone else avoid that!